Sci-fi book (all-knowing cow, almost grey goo beginning, different universe/dimension)
Someone created self-replicating nanobots that replicated enough only to replace every other few nano particles. The consequence is that privacy is impossible as every nanobot has a camera and you can see anything from any angle. What I remember next is that there's an excursion in another universe or dimension where the dominant sentient beings are bigger than us. Lastly, the detail that should make it unique to other books is that there's a cow, either metaphorical or literal, that is all-knowing where if you suck it you get knowledge about what you're thinking about and more. Thanks in advance.

In roughly which year did you read this? Also, I assumed you meant to say "where if you suck it" rather than "where it you suck it" and edited the question accordingly. If I misunderstood your intention, please edit the question yourself to fix it.

What does "replace every other few nano particles" mean?

@LogicDictates your edit is correct. I think 15 to 10 years ago is when I read it. I got it from the library and I didn't have the electronic record because I lost the account.

@FreeMan I just mean that the self replicating nanobots replicated enough only to be among every object including people.
